# Search all positions of char in string and return as comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have string (`VARCHAR(255)`) that contains only zeros or ones.
I need to search all positions and return them as comma separated string.
I've build two queries using solutions from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/how-to-find-all-positions-of-a-string-within-another-string

Here is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @TERM VARCHAR(5);
SET @TERM = '1';
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(255);
SET @STRING = '101011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000';

DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(100);
SET @RESULT = '';

SELECT
   @RESULT = @RESULT + CAST(X.pos AS VARCHAR(10)) + ','
FROM
   ( SELECT
      pos = Number - LEN(@TERM)
     FROM
      ( SELECT
         Number
        ,Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@STRING, Number, CHARINDEX(@TERM, @STRING + @TERM, Number) - Number)))
        FROM
         ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects
         ) AS n ( Number )
        WHERE
         Number > 1
         AND Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@STRING))
         AND SUBSTRING(@TERM + @STRING, Number, LEN(@TERM)) = @TERM
      ) AS y
   ) X;

SELECT
   SUBSTRING(@RESULT, 0, LEN(@RESULT));



DECLARE @POS INT;
DECLARE @OLD_POS INT;
DECLARE @POSITIONS VARCHAR(100);
SELECT
   @POSITIONS = '';
SELECT
   @OLD_POS = 0;
SELECT
   @POS = PATINDEX('%1%', @STRING); 
WHILE @POS > 0
   AND @OLD_POS <> @POS
   BEGIN
      SELECT
         @POSITIONS = @POSITIONS + CAST(@POS AS VARCHAR(2)) + ',';
      SELECT
         @OLD_POS = @POS;
      SELECT
         @POS = PATINDEX('%1%', SUBSTRING(@STRING, @POS + 1, LEN(@STRING))) + @POS;
   END;
SELECT
   LEFT(@POSITIONS, LEN(@POSITIONS) - 1);
```

I'm wondering if this can be done faster/better? I'm searching only for single character positions and I have only two characters that can occur in my string (0 and 1).

I've build two functions using this code, and run them for 1000 records and got same results in same time, so I can't tell which one is better.

for single record second part gives CPU and reads equals to 0 in Profiler, where first piece of code give me CPU=16 and reads=17.

I need to get result that looks like this: `1,3,5,6,8,9` (when multiple occurrences), `3` for single occurence, `NONE` if there are no ones.

Comment: Does this _have_ to be done in SQL?  What's the purpose of identifying all of the positions that are `1`?

Comment: Ideally, change the required output, and possible the storage design as well. Comma separated values stuffed into a string ought to be a *last* resort if you need to deal with multiple values. SQL Server has types *designed* for holding multiple values, such as *tables* and XML.

Comment: @DStanley I have table that has holds options. There are 100 columns. This is a very old database. There can be only single value for row, for example single `1` for row, but for old rows there were errors. I'm creating report that searches for those rows and list them. I've converted values to 01 string, now I need to know position of ones to have option number.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I can't change the output, this is one of requirements I got. I must display rows with invalid values (more than one 1 per row) in format described in my question

Comment: @Misiu if there's any possibility of doing that in the app layer it will be much easier.  SQL is not designed for those types of non-set-based operations.

Comment: @DStanley I'm aware of that, but on the other hand loading 10 millions+ records to app and doing logic there is something I'd like to avoid. I'd like to do all on server and simply get results. I need result as simple excel, no need for application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `tally` table and `xml` solution:

```
DECLARE @STRING NVARCHAR(100) = '101011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000';

;with cte as(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) p 
             from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1(n) cross join
                  (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t2(n) cross join
                  (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t3(n))
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(p AS VARCHAR(100))
              FROM cte
              WHERE p <= LEN(@STRING) AND SUBSTRING(@STRING, p, 1) = '1'
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

You just generate numbers from 1 to 1000(add more joins if length of string is bigger) and with `substring` function filter needed values. Then standard trick for concatenating rows to comma separated value.

For old versions:

```
;with cte as(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) p
             FROM sys.all_columns a CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns b)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(p AS VARCHAR(100))
              FROM cte
              WHERE p <= LEN(@STRING) AND SUBSTRING(@STRING, p, 1) = '1'
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Here is a good article on generating ranges http://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/

**EDIT:**

```
;with cte as(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) p
               FROM (SELECT 1 AS rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) t1 CROSS JOIN 
                (SELECT 1 AS rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) t2 CROSS JOIN 
                (SELECT 1 AS rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) t3 CROSS JOIN 
                (SELECT 1 AS rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) t4 CROSS JOIN 
                (SELECT 1 AS rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) t5 CROSS JOIN 
                (SELECT 1 AS rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) t6)
```

Comment: Thank You for such fast reply, but I can't get it working on SQL Server 2005. I get error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.`

Comment: Now it works fine, thank You. Could You describe in couple of words why this is better/faster than my two solutions? all three works, but I can't say which one is better

Comment: Cursors are slow comparing to setbased statements. Also you should not use cursors just because syntax allow you to do this. Whenever you can manage to do without cursor it is preferable to do so.

Comment: I've just compared @josephstyons solution and it is bit faster and shows less CPU and reads. I've tested this on 140k rows.

Comment: Now it looks faster. One more question: how to determinate size of tally table? for example if my string will be max 50 characters how many columns and rows that table should have (how many `UNION ALL` and `CROSS JOIN`)?

Comment: @Misiu, cross join will give you a cartesian. In the example I have 5 `select 1`s so the number of rows will be 5*5*5*5*5*5 = 15625. Enough for any string you might have. Just have some large number of rows. But you are filtering outside by length, so it will not hurt performance if you add more joins. Optimizer is clever enough.

Answer (score 1):

Giorgi's response is very clever, but I'd prefer a more old-fashioned approach that's more readable.  My suggestion, including test cases:

```
if object_id('UFN_CSVPOSITIONS') is not null
begin
  drop function ufn_csvpositions;
end
go

create function dbo.UFN_CSVPOSITIONS
(
  @string nvarchar(255)
 ,@delimiter nvarchar(1) = ','
)
returns nvarchar(255)
as
begin
  --given a string that contains ones,
  --return a comma-delimited list of the positions of those ones
  --example: '1001' returns '1,4'
  declare @result nvarchar(255) = '';
  declare @i int = 1;
  declare @slen int = len(@string);
  declare @idx int = 0;

  while @i < @slen
  begin
    set @idx = charindex('1',@string,@i);
    if 0 = @idx
    begin
      set @i = @slen;  --no more to be found, break out early
    end
    else
    begin
      set @result = @result + @delimiter + convert(nvarchar(3),@idx);
      set @i = @idx; --jump ahead
    end;
    set @i = @i + 1;
  end  --while

  if (0 < len(@result)) and (',' = substring(@result,1,1))
  begin
    set @result = substring(@result,2,len(@result)-1)
  end

  return @result;
end
go

--test cases
DECLARE @STRING NVARCHAR(255) = '';
set @string = '101011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
print dbo.UFN_CSVPOSITIONS(@string,',');
set @string = null;
print dbo.UFN_CSVPOSITIONS(@string,',');
set @string = '';
print dbo.UFN_CSVPOSITIONS(@string,',');
set @string = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';
print dbo.UFN_CSVPOSITIONS(@string,',');
set @string = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
print dbo.UFN_CSVPOSITIONS(@string,',');

--lets try a very large # of test cases, see how fast it comes out
--255 "ones" should be the worst case scenario for performance, so lets run through 50k of those.
--on my laptop, here are test case results:
--all 1s   : 13 seconds
--all 0s   :  7 seconds
--all nulls:  1 second
declare @testinput nvarchar(255) = replicate('1',255);
declare @iterations int = 50000;
declare @i int = 0;
while @i < @iterations
begin
  print dbo.ufn_csvpositions(@testinput,',');
  set @i = @i + 1;
end;

--repeat the test using the CTE method.
--the same test cases are as follows on my local:
--all 1s   : 18 seconds
--all 0s   : 15 seconds
--all NULLs: 1  second
set nocount on;
set @i = 0;
set @iterations = 50000;
declare @result nvarchar(255) = '';
set @testinput = replicate('1',255);
while @i < @iterations
begin
  ;with cte as(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) p
               FROM sys.all_columns a CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns b)
  SELECT @result = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(p AS VARCHAR(100))
                FROM cte
                WHERE p <= LEN(@testinput) AND SUBSTRING(@testinput, p, 1) = '1'
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
  print @result;
  set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

Comment: I have solution that is using `while` loop, but thanks for Your answer and time spend. I was searching for fastest way of doing this. Your code is easier to read, but I think @giorgi-nakeuri code is much faster. Sorry if I'm wrong, but I'm newbie if it comes to SQL query optimization.

Comment: When I compare the performance of the two approaches, the WHILE loop is faster.  I've edited the answer to include test cases for both approaches; try it out on your machine and see if your experience is the same.

Comment: I must confirm that version with WHILE is bit faster. I've tested that with 140k rows and CPU and reads were smaller with WHILE approach. I must test that on bigger dataset.

Comment: @JosephStyons, it was because of selecting from sys tables... See my answer for another version of tally and check. Now mine beats yours..

Comment: I can confirm that as well - on my machine, doing 50,000 "all 1s" strings takes 11 seconds, compared to 18 before, and 13s with the while loop.  I stand by my assertion that the clarity of code is worth the fractional loss in performance, but that's a trade-off for the OP to decide about.  In any case, most impressive!

Comment: I modified the loop-based approach with some optimizations that I think will improve performance in most real-world scenarios.  You may want to try it out on your actual data and see how it performs.