# can i able to get the position for multiple character by charindex in a single query in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

can i able to get the position for multiple character by `charindex` in a single query in **SQL**?

```
declare @name varchar(100) ='kalee@swara@n@r'
 
select CHARINDEX('@',@name)
 
select CHARINDEX('@',@name,7)

select CHARINDEX('@',@name,13) ;
```

Comment: No, `CHARINDEX` returns only a single value, unless you concatenated the values together in a delimted string through multiple calls to `CHARINDEX`, or something like that.  What exactly are you using this for?  Maybe there's a better idea?

Comment: Please be specific about what you want. Do you want to find the position of exactly three occurences of `@`? Or up to 3? Or all occurences, with potentially all characters being `@`? *(Note; if you don't know how many `@` symbols you're looking for, you probably need recursion, with each symbol's position value being on a new result row, rather than multiple columns on the same row.)* Or, perhaps you don't actually want the `@` symbols, you want the text separated by them? In which case looking in to `string_split()`

Comment: do you want to return in single query?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do here? Get a result set per appearance of a character in a string? A *set* of characters in a string? Are you looking for one row per position, a delimited list, something else?

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478093/5193536

Comment: i want to find the position of exactly three occurences of '@'

Comment: For eg- I have a table column tha t contains values such as  ,`abc_1_2_3_4.com` or `zzz_12_3_3_45.com` etc. I want to find each `underscore`  positions by using `charindex ` ,How can I achieve?

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to return it in single query as below?

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('@',@name),
       CHARINDEX('@',@name,7),
       CHARINDEX('@',@name,13)'
```

Comment: Your clarifying questions should be asked in the comments section. You seem to have submitted your question disguised as an answer :-)